# Counterexample for uniform convergence of optimal L2 polynomial approximation

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, examples-counterexamples

Let $f \in \mathcal{C}([a,b])$  where $a$, $b$ are finite, and let $\{\phi_j\}$ be an increasing-in-degree orthogonal basis for the polynomials with respect to some weight function $w(x)\geq0$. The unique least-squares approximating polynomial exists and is defined by $$r_n^*(x) \equiv {\arg\min}_{p\in\mathcal{P}^n} \Vert f - p\Vert_{L_w^2}$$

It can be shown$^1$ that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Vert f - r_n^*\Vert_{L_w^2} = 0$$ but that this *does not imply uniform convergence*.

Could someone provide a counterexample that illustrates this property?

---

$^1$e.g., Thm. 4.7 *An Introduction to Numerical Analysis, 2nd Ed.*; Atkinson, 2004